# php -S localhost:8000 not running in node.js

Tags: node.js, npm

I have installed NPM and bower globally as well as gulp and I am trying to run the following command on a windows machine:

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

Its saying php is not recognized as an internal or external command. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

THanks

Comment: What's the link between php, npm, and gulp? The error means you don't have php executable, but I'm a bit confused about the mix of tech in your question.

Comment: Yea, i've downloaded a package for a project and the documentation says to run that command to launch. Is there a package I can install to allow running php commands? Sorry if htis is unclear, i'm new to this!

Comment: I'm neither a php developer nor I use windows, but I believe you might want to start here: http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.legacy.index.php#install.windows.legacy.commandline

Answer (score 0):

Installing PHP solved this for me, specifically following this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Y6lOHov3Bk